# Putty in ConEmu on Win7 Enterprise

Tags: putty, conemu

(Please note that putty works fine in conemu on Windows 10 Home for me)

In Windows 7 Enterprise none of the following work - all of them open putty in an external window.

```
putty.exe -load "veragld"
```

opens putty in a separate window.

```
putty.exe -new_console -load "veragld"
```

With `Features->Inject ConEmuHk` enabled, this gives me an "injecting hooks" error, then opens putty in a separate window. With `Inject ConEmuHk` disabled (but with `Process '-new_console'...` enabled) conemu does not parse *-new_console* and I get a putty error. Ditto for *-cur_console*.

Any permutations of the above give me either the hook injection error or putty in a separate window. On Windows 10 Home it all "just works" with -new_console.

Could the corporate McAfee crapware be blocking somehow? Any suggestions?

ConEmu 170402 preview

Thanks!

Edit: @Maximus - I get this in the original conemu console after the hook injection error:

```
Process was not attached to console. Is it GUI?

Current directory:
C:\Users\me

Command to be executed:
"c:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\putty.exe" -load "veragld"


Press Ctrl+Break to stop waiting


Press Enter or Esc to close console, or wait...
```

Same results, though, whether I run it from the console or as a task.

Edit #2: `> notepad -new_console` works just fine. Dunno why.

Comment: Make your Putty settings the same. Run putty using full path to exe.

Comment: @Maximus - thanks for getting back to me, didn't want to spam the github page. Same exact results if I specify the full path to putty.exe...

Comment: Putty settings are default except for foreground/background colors and font (Consolas), same as W10 Home. FYI.

Comment: Unbelievable. Something in your putty config prevents the attach.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to display the interaction? A dev version of conemu that dumps a full log in realtime or something? It's difficult to compare my "home" putty layout to my "work" layout, I have no access from home and vice versa...

Comment: Release version of ConEmu started with `-log` switch. I suppose the reason preventing the detach will be visible in log.

Comment: There's nothing in the logs that gives me any hints, but I'm not a conemu developer :-) I will send them to you if you want and/or post them on the github forum, just let me know if you're interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mputty gave me a hard time as well (would not load/interface with putty.exe). I was able to get mputty work to well with putty by running it (mputty) with `run elevated` - this approach does not work, however, with multi-threaded applications which I assume conemu is. I believe this is why conemu would not load putty (but would load notepad of all things???).

@maximus: problem solved - I finally finished swimming the boiling black sea of IT politics and was granted Admin rights on my work laptop. Running conemu with admin rights, putty works just fine in a new_console. FYI.